# How to setState(!state) in Redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I'm new to RTK, I've been learning from tutorials for the last few days, I know how to deal with arrays, and increment or decrement the value, but I can't wrap my head around the simplest thing in RTK is toggling state. So far I have written this code :

```
 import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
    dropdown: false
}

const dropdownSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'dropdown',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setDropdown: state  =>  !state
    }
});

export const {
    setDropdown
} = dropdownSlice.actions
export default dropdownSlice.reducer
```

and then in my component I did this

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import {GiHamburgerMenu} from 'react-icons/gi'
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import { setDropdown } from '../../redux/slices/dropdownSlice'
import dropdownSlice from '../../redux/slices/dropdownSlice'
import './Nav.scss'


        const Nav = () => {
            const [width,setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth)
            // const [dropdown,setDropdown] = useState(false);
            const dispatch = useDispatch()
            const checkDropdown = () =>{
              dispatch(setDropdown);
            }
        
            const checkWidth = () =>{
                setWidth(window.innerWidth)
                // if(width > 600){
                //     setDropdown(false);
                // }
                // console.log(width);
            }
            useEffect(() =>{
                window.addEventListener('resize', checkWidth)
                return () => window.removeEventListener('resize',checkWidth)
            },[])
            return (
              <nav>
                <header>
                  <div className="logo">
    ....
                  </div>
                  <div className="links">
                      {width > 600 ?
                    <ul>
                      ....
                    </ul>
                    :
                    <GiHamburgerMenu className='icon' onClick={()=> checkDropdown()}/>}
                  </div>
                </header>
                <div
                  className={
                    dropdownSlice.dropdown ? "dropdown dropdown-show" : "dropdown dropdown-hide"
                  }
        .............
                    >
```

Pls help, I've aged 3 years in 2 days trying to learn rtk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two bugs:

1. Your reducer does not keep it's shape. It goes from `{ dropdown: false }` to `false` to `true` to `false` to `true`.

This goes `{ dropdown: false }` <-> `{ dropdown: true }`

```js
const initialState = {
    dropdown: false
}

const dropdownSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'dropdown',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setDropdown: (state) => { state.dropdown = !state.dropdown }
    }
});
```

This goes `false`<->`true`:

```js
const initialState = false

const dropdownSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'dropdown',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setDropdown: state => !state
    }
});
```

2. you need to execute your action creator before dispatching

```js
dispatch(setDropdown());
```

Comment: This works, the state is changing, however, this part where I wanna change className on click doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: You have to use `useSelector` to get data from your redux state. Directly accessing your imported slice will do nothing, since the slice just contains information on how state is changed, but not any state itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your state is an object containing the `dropdown`

```
const dropdownSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'dropdown',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setDropdown: state  =>  !state.dropdown
    }
});
```